# Neo4j - can't get all the records from a "parent-child" relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

Here are my classes:

```
class Author
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :author_name,  type: String
  property :author_id,    type: Integer
  has_many :out, :wokas
end

class Woka
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :author_id,    type: Integer
  property :publisher_id, type: Integer
  property :language_id,  type: Integer
  property :woka_id,      type: Integer
  property :woka_title,   type: String
  has_one :in, :author
  has_one :in, :publisher
  has_one :in, :language
end
```

Woka is a "child" of Author.

I am executing from RoR something like this:

```
a = Author.find_by(author_name: 'Camus, Albert')
w = Woka.find_by(woka_title: 'Caligula')
```

The first one is correct, there is only one Author.
The second one is not, since many authors wrote about Caligula.

Here is the extract from the dev log for those two statement above:

```
 [36mCYPHER[0m [33m138ms[0m MATCH (n:`Author`) WHERE (n.author_name = {n_author_name}) RETURN n LIMIT {limit_1} | {:n_author_name=>"Camus, Albert", "limit_1"=>1}

 [36mCYPHER[0m [33m126ms[0m MATCH (n:`Woka`) WHERE (n.woka_title = {n_woka_title}) RETURN n LIMIT {limit_1} | {:n_woka_title=>"Caligula", "limit_1"=>1}
```

Why those "limit_1"=>1 are generated by the gem? I did not requested any limitation of the result set.

The query written in cypher returns the right number of rows: 31.

```
MATCH (w:Woka) WHERE (w.woka_title = 'Caligula') MATCH (a:Author)-[:AUTHORED]->(w:Woka) RETURN w.woka_id, w.woka_title as woka_title, a.author_name as author_name;
```

Don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase [the documentation](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Search-and-Match):

> find_by behaves as it does in ActiveRecord, returning the first object
>   matching the criteria.

I think you want to use these statements instead, to get all possible results:

```
a = Author.all.where(author_name: 'Camus, Albert')
w = Woka.all.where(woka_title: 'Caligula')
```

Comment: I just figured out myself the same only couple minutes ago. Many thanks anyway for the hint.